# Как следует переводить "Help Center"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Пожалуйста, предложите ваш вариант перевода "Help Center".  В частности для заголовка [раздела справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Почему мы не можем оставить как есть? Потому, что для некоторых разделов «Справочный Центр» ломает разметку. Например, раздел описания [знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Вместо "Справочный центр" использовать "Справка".